# C++ floor() decreasing value by 1

Tags: c++, floor

I wrote this function to recursively round a `double` to N digits:

```
double RoundDouble(double value, unsigned int digits)
{
    if (value == 0.0)
        return value;
    string num = dtos(value);
    size_t found = num.find(".");
    string dec = "";
    if (found != string::npos)
        dec = num.substr(found + 1);
    else
        return value;
    if (dec.length() <= digits)
    {
        LogToFile("C:\\test.txt", "RETURN: " + dtos(value) + "\n\n\n");
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        double p10 = pow(10, (dec.length() - 1));
        LogToFile("C:\\test.txt", "VALUE: " + dtos(value) + "\n");
        double mul = value * p10;
        LogToFile("C:\\test.txt", "MUL: " + dtos(mul) + "\n");
        double sum = mul + 0.5;
        LogToFile("C:\\test.txt", "SUM: " + dtos(sum) + "\n");
        double floored = floor(sum);
        LogToFile("C:\\test.txt", "FLOORED: " + dtos(floored) + "\n");
        double div = floored / p10;
        LogToFile("C:\\test.txt", "DIV: " + dtos(div) + "\n-------\n");
        return RoundDouble(div, digits);
    }
}
```

But as from the log file, something really strange is happening with floor() in some cases...

Here's an output example of good calculation:

```
VALUE: 2.0108
MUL: 2010.8
SUM: 2011.3
FLOORED: 2011
DIV: 2.011
-------
VALUE: 2.011
MUL: 201.1
SUM: 201.6
FLOORED: 201
DIV: 2.01
-------
RETURN: 2.01
```

And here's an output example of bad calculation:

```
VALUE: 67.6946
MUL: 67694.6
SUM: 67695.1
FLOORED: 67695
DIV: 67.695
-------
VALUE: 67.695
MUL: 6769.5
SUM: 6770
FLOORED: 6769 <= PROBLEM HERE
DIV: 67.69
-------
RETURN: 67.69
```

Isn't floor(6770) supposed to return 6770? Why is it returning 6769?

Comment: Because it's not not actually 6770, but something very close to it. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: "Isn't floor(6770) supposed to return 6770?" That's not true for small values of 6770.

Comment: Try adding an epsilon value to the floor, it sounds like the value is really 6769 with decimals making it close to 6770.

Comment: So many possible duplicates...

Comment: So it's not 6770 but something like 6769.9999(...)9? But by converting that double to string it says 6770. What if i get the string value from it and then convert it back to double? Is it a dumb solution or may that work?

Comment: I would add an epsilon value instead of trying that.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `double floored = floor(sum + 1 - numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());`

Comment: if you want to *round* a number to n digits then somewhere there has to be a rounding process so for one digit thus floor((val*10)+0.5) * 10.0; The 0.5 ensures that you are actually rounding, or just use round(val*10)/10.0;

Comment: @TimBergel the rounding process is basically `floor((value * p10) + 0.5) / p10` i simply splitted it to get each calculation and figure out where the problem was (in floor())

Comment: I'm an idiot - missed the 0.5

Comment: Btw i just tested and adding 1 - epsilon (if i'm adding it properly) seems to not fit my needs as it's too big and the final rounded values are increased by 0.1 in most of the cases. While floor(stod(dtos(sum))) gives exactly the expected result. Dont know if that's the best solution but for now it seems to be the only one working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all thanks everyone for the suggestions.
Btw for the moment the "double to string -> string to double -> floor" solution seems to be the only one giving exactly the expected result.
So i just needed to replace:

```
double floored = floor(sum);
```

with

```
double floored = floor(stod(dtos(sum)));
```

If anyone has a better solution please post it.